# Can't execute command in Perl script

Tags: perl

first of all, i'm totally new to Perl and i need to remove a string from a file.

Code i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

my $server_a = 'xxx.test.ch';

print "$server_a\n";
perl -pli -e "s/$server_a//" '/Users/user/Downloads/exports';
```

When i execute this script i get this error:

```
syntax error at nfs_test.sh line 9, near "pli -e "
Execution of nfs_test.sh aborted due to compilation errors.
```

i cant find whats wrong, i hope you can help me.

Comment: You are calling perl in a perl file?

Comment: i thought that was the mistake, but i don't know how to solve it..

Comment: What you are trying to do here?

Comment: The file 'export' is a big config file and i need to remove every xxx.test.ch entry in that file, if i run the command "perl -pli -e "s/$server_a//" '/Users/user/Downloads/exports';" in Bash it works (obviously..) but how can i do that in perl..?

Comment: Why you Need it in perl can't you use it in bash?

Comment: @Jens it has to be perl, can't use bash at all.

Comment: then you have to open the file Change the strings and write it back into an other file. If you have done it, you have to rename the out file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

@ARGV = '/Users/user/Downloads/exports';
$^I = '~';

my $server_a = quotemeta 'xxx.test.ch';
s/$server_a//, print while <>;
```

The @ARGV array contains the arguments, it's iterated by the diamond operator.

`$^I` is equivalent to the `-i` option.

You probably need [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta), as you don't mean "anything but newline" by dots in the server name.

Comment: before i try it out and ruin it, i'll try to understand yours. So basically every line, that doesn't contains xxx.test.ch will stay the same but every line that contains xxx.test.ch will be removed, correct?

Comment: what if it contains "-sec=lala.test.ch:tutu.test.ch:xxx.test.ch:gege.test.ch"?

Comment: @Damon: Fixed by using substitution as in your original code.